# How to assign keys on physical position at the keyboard on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

There are at least 3 different keyboard layouts who are using the program i make, and i dont care which key they press, the more important thing is where the keys are pressed.

I cant just ask the user to press 100 different keys/combinations, that would take too much time and be very confusing to the user.

Is there some library or something that can do this for me?

Comment: I really think you're out of luck, the keyboard sends the key code pressed, not where the key is. For example my keyboard has `\\` in the top right, but some have it in the bottom left, yet they all send the same keycode.

Comment: The answer to this will be much more MS Windows-specific than C++-specific (the language doesn't even have the concept of a keyboard), so you might want to change the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. Keyboards do not come with their layout in an electronic form, that could be looked up by the OS. They just send the code for the key pressed, not where the key resides. I'm working on several keyboards daily, which are all classified as having German layout, but with some of the keys being in different places.

The only way to find out at what physical position a specific key is on a specific keyboard is to look at what's printed on the key.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394902/how-to-determine-if-a-certain-key-is-pressed-knowing-only-its-position-on-u-s/394906#394906) says that you can use the keyboard "Scan Code" which should be the same on all keyboards. So it appears that there is in fact a way to determine the key location.

Even without using the scan code, you could implement a mapping table for all the keyboard layouts you support. So if the keyboard layout is US English, the key would map to command A, but on layout German German, it would map to command B, and some other command would map to command A. It may not work for all keyboards, but if it works for all of your users that's what matters. I can see why you were looking for an existing library to do this as it would be a significant amount of work.